# Data Studio - Few events from GA in one chart line

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I want to show aggregated events in one chart line. I am using a filter to choose events and then I have a few lines:

[image: CHART-IMAGE]

How do I add the events values in one line?

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved by **Removing** the **Breakdown Dimension** (for example `Event Action`), such that the chart would be structured as (using a [Time Series](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7059697)):

- ***Dimension***: `Date`
- ***Metric***: `Unique Events` (or the required metric)

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/4e63881f-3e3b-415f-a398-e552331eb3f5) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have unique events as metric.

Keep the filter and remove 'event category' from dimension field in the chart builder.